# Is this proof that $X=Y$ implies $x\in X\iff x\in Y$ good?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing, first-order-logic

I am trying to prove
$$\forall X\forall Y(X=Y\implies\forall x(x\in X\iff x\in Y))$$

This is the converse of the axiom of extensionality.

$$\forall X\forall Y(\forall x(x\in X\iff x\in Y)\implies X=Y)$$

I am practicing making proofs as I don't have much practice.

I am worried that I am using universal generalization wrong.

Here is my work:
(First-order identity is assumed.)

1. $X=Y$ assumption
2. $x\in X$ assumption
3. $x\in Y$ substitution 1,2
4. $x\in X$ substitution 1,3
5. $x\in X\implies x\in Y$ conditional introduction 2,3
6. $x\in Y\implies x\in X$ conditional introduction 3,4
7. $x\in X\iff x\in Y$ biconditional introduction 5,6
8. $\forall x(x\in X\iff x\in Y)$ universal generalization x/x 7
9. $X=Y\implies\forall x(x\in X\iff x\in Y)$ conditional introduction 1,8
10. $\forall Y(X=Y\implies\forall x(x\in X\iff x\in Y))$ universal generalization Y/Y 9
11. $\forall X\forall Y(X=Y\implies\forall x(x\in X\iff x\in Y))$ universal generalization X/X 10

Is the proof good? Can I make it better?

Comment: That looks good to me.

Comment: There is a mistake using conditional intro in 6. Line 3 is not an assumption but is a conclusion, so you shouldn't cite it for 6.

Comment: But the universal intro looks good

Comment: Agree with IsAdisplayname here. You technically need to do $4. \ x\in X \implies x\in Y \ \text{(conditional introduction 2,3)}$ and then start another subproof with $5.\ x \in Y \text{ (assumption)}$, and then $6.\ x \in X \text{ (substitution 1, 4)}$. The universal generalization is correct, however.

Comment: Thank you all!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the conditional introduction on line 6 is not right.  You need to make a separate assumption of $x \in Y$ to get to $x\in Y\implies x\in X$. It's an easy fix:

1. $X=Y$ assumption
2. $x\in X$ assumption
3. $x\in Y$ substitution 1,2
4. $x\in X\implies x\in Y$ conditional introduction 2,3
5. $x\in Y$ assumption
6. $x\in X$ substitution 1,5
7. $x\in Y\implies x\in X$ conditional introduction 5,6
8. $x\in X\iff x\in Y$ biconditional introduction 4,7
9. $\forall x(x\in X\iff x\in Y)$ universal generalization x/x 8
10. $X=Y\implies\forall x(x\in X\iff x\in Y)$ conditional introduction 1,9
11. $\forall Y(X=Y\implies\forall x(x\in X\iff x\in Y))$ universal generalization Y/Y 10
12. $\forall X\forall Y(X=Y\implies\forall x(x\in X\iff x\in Y))$ universal generalization X/X 11

Comment: In line 5 the assumption that you added is $x\in X$ still though. Should it be $x\in Y$?

Comment: @IsaacSechslingloff Whoops! Of course, yes, I forgot to switch the assumption and the goal. Fixed

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks))